# minus operator in oracle for the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use minus operator to the same table to show duplicate records by using distinct key word in the second query but the query result was no rows selected.so So what is the explanation of this ?

select column1 from my_table
minus
select distinct(column1) from my_table;

Comment: If you need to find duplicate values, with a search you'll find many good answers in SO. If you have a different issue, please post some sample data and desired result to better explain your need.

Answer (score 0):

> "so what is the explanation of this select column1 from my_table minus select distinct(column1) from my_table;"

The MINUS operator produces a result set of all the values in the top sub query which are not in the lower sub query. It is a SET, which means it only returns unique values (so the use of `distinct` is unnecessary). Clearly in your query all the values in the lower sub-query are in the upper sub-query, hence the empty result set.

To find duplicated values you need to use an aggregate function. This HAVING clause will return only values of `column1` which occur more than once.

```
select column1 , count(*)
from my_table 
group by column1 having count(*) > 1;
```